# Sub-collection sum

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

I have following classes:

```
    class UserData(
        val firstSale: Date,
        val lastSale: Date,
        val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
        val taxList: List<ItemSale>,
        val salesList: List<ItemSale>,
        val taxTotal: Long,
        val saleTotal: Long,
        val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
        val canceledOrderCount: Int,
        val canceledSaleTotal: Long,
    )
```

And model class:

```
class ItemSale(
       val itemDescription: String,
       val itemsTotalValue: Long
)
```

I'm fetchig all my UserData objects from my db:

```
dbRepository.getAllUsersData(): List<UserData>
```

And now i dont know how to sum this List UserData objects and return as single object i mean, i have no idea how to sum those lists taxList/saleList included in UserData object. In those lists i need to sum itemsTotalValue.

Example:

We have list of two UserData objects:

```
//1    
class UserData(
            val firstSale: 238402384092L,
            val lastSale: 893231117482L,
            val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
            val taxList: List<ItemSale>, // ("first", 4), ("second", 4)
            val salesList: List<ItemSale>, // ("third", 5), ("fourth", 3)
            val taxTotal: 500,
            val saleTotal: 600,
            val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
            val canceledOrderCount: 3,
            val canceledSaleTotal: 4500
    )
  
//2  
  class UserData(
            val firstSale: 338402384092L,
            val lastSale: 9934798237482L,
            val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
            val taxList: List<ItemSale>, // ("first", 7), ("second", 8)
            val salesList: List<ItemSale>, // ("third", 1), ("fourth", 2)
            val taxTotal: 250,
            val saleTotal: 400,
            val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
            val canceledOrderCount: 4,
            val canceledSaleTotal: 400
    )
```

We need to sum them like this:

```
//Result 1 + 2
class UserData(
        val firstSale: 238402384092L,
        val lastSale: 9934798237482L,
        val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>, //Stay same for all objects
        val taxList: List<ItemSale>, // ("first", 11), ("second", 12)
        val salesList: List<ItemSale>, // ("third", 6), ("fourth", 5)
        val taxTotal: 750,
        val saleTotal: 1000,
        val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY, // Stay for all same
        val canceledOrderCount: 7,
        val canceledSaleTotal: 4900
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked specifically for `taxList` and `salesList`, I'll ignore all other properties and focus on them. We can calculate the sum of `taxList` with this code:

```kotlin
val data: List<UserData> = ...

val taxList = data.asSequence()
    .flatMap { it.taxList }
    .groupingBy { it.itemDescription }
    .fold(0L) { acc, item -> acc + item.itemsTotalValue }
    .map { ItemSale(it.key, it.value) }
```

We will go trough this code step by step:

1. `flatMap()` merges all `taxList` properties from all `UserData` objects into a single list of `ItemSale` objects. It contains duplicates, e.g. multiple `first` items.
2. `groupingBy()` groups `ItemSale` items by their name/description. We can then easily work on e.g. `first` items separately from other items.
3. `fold()` is where summing really happens. It works on each above group separately, it starts summing with `0L` value and with each new item (e.g. each new `first` item), it adds `itemsTotalValue` to the accumulated value.
4. At this point we have a `Map<String, Long>` where keys are `itemDescription` strings and values are summed `itemsTotalValue` properties of items with this specific `itemDescription`.
5. Finally, we need to convert the map into a list of `ItemSale` which we do in `map` step.

As we use `asSequence()` and `groupingBy()` (instead of `groupBy()`), all data is calculated lazily. That means it works as we would iterate over all items sequentially, calculating the result while iterating. This is good for performance reasons.

`salesList` can be calculated in exactly the same way, we just need to modify `flatMap()` step.

The resulting function for merging the list of `UserData` objects:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val data: List<UserData> = ...
    println(data.merge())
}

fun Iterable<UserData>.merge(): UserData {
    requireNotNull(firstOrNull()) // require not empty

    fun mergeItems(selector: (UserData) -> List<ItemSale>) = asSequence()
        .flatMap(selector)
        .groupingBy { it.itemDescription }
        .fold(0L) { acc, item -> acc + item.itemsTotalValue }
        .map { ItemSale(it.key, it.value) }

    return UserData(
        firstSale = minOf(UserData::firstSale),
        lastSale = maxOf(UserData::lastSale),
        ptuCodesList = first().ptuCodesList, // not sure what to return here
        taxList = mergeItems(UserData::taxList),
        salesList = mergeItems(UserData::salesList),
        taxTotal = sumOf(UserData::taxTotal),
        saleTotal = sumOf(UserData::saleTotal),
        currency = first().currency, // not sure what to return here
        canceledOrderCount = sumOf(UserData::canceledOrderCount),
        canceledSaleTotal = sumOf(UserData::canceledSaleTotal),
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you broot for answer with amazing detailed explanation! I've got new question to those objects: Lets say that during this summing i want to take lowest "firstSale" date and highest "lastSale" date. How do i achieve that?

Comment: You mean something like: `data.minByOrNull { it.firstSale }` and `data.maxByOrNull { it.lastSale }`? You can also do simple summing like this: `data.sumOf { it.taxTotal }`.

Comment: Actually, not `minByOrNull()` and `maxByOrNull()`, but `minOf()` and `maxOf()` instead. I added a full example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Jumanji,

You need to do this step by step, i.e. separately calculate each field you need to calculate and at the end just create an instance of UserData using those calculated fields.

Getting more into details - you can create helper method to concatenate ("sum") two lists of `List<ItemSale>` which could look like this:

```
private fun concatenateItemSales(sales1: List<ItemSale>, sales2: List<ItemSale>): List<ItemSale> {
    val itemsFromSales1ConcatenatedWithSales2: List<ItemSale> = sales1.map { item1 ->
        val item2Value: Long? = sales2.find { it.itemDescription == item1.itemDescription }?.itemsTotalValue
        val itemsTotalValue = item1.itemsTotalValue + (item2Value ?: 0L)
        ItemSale(item1.itemDescription, itemsTotalValue)
    }
    val sales1ItemDescriptions: List<String> = sales1.map { it.itemDescription }
    val itemsFromSales2NotInSales1: List<ItemSale> = sales2.filter { it.itemDescription !in sales1ItemDescriptions }

    return itemsFromSales1ConcatenatedWithSales2 + itemsFromSales2NotInSales1
}
```

This function assumes possible occurence of items that are present only in one of these two lists - for safety reasons. If you're sure there always be exactly same items (with same descriptions) and there will no such differences - you can always simplify this code.
You can also improve code this function to use functional style like one presented by broot in the another answer. I focused more on idea than on providing best possible code.

Having this function it should be easy for you to create concatenated `UserData`, e.g. this way:

```
class UserData(...) {

  operator fun plus(anotherData: UserData): UserData {
    val firstSale = min(this.firstSale, anotherData.firstSale)
    val taxList = concatenateItemSales(this.taxList, anotherData.taxList)
    val salesList = conatenateItemSales(this.salesList, anotherData.salesList)
    val taxTotal = this.taxTotal + anotherData.taxTotal
    // and similarly calculate the other fields you need

   return UserData(firstSale, ..., taxList, salesList, taxTotal, ...)
  }
}
```

Now you can sum / concatenate two UserData instances just using `+` operator like this:

```
val userData1: UserData = UserData(...)
val userData2: UserData = UserData(...)
val conacatenatedUserData = userData1 + userData2
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel really good answer! I've got new question to those objects: Lets say that during this summing i want to take lowest "firstSale" date and highest "lastSale" date. How do i achieve that?

Comment: Look at `plus` method where I already showed how to get lowest firstSale date. Similarly you can take highest lastSale using `max` function as the dates are provided as numbers (timestamps) so it's as easy as that.